# Items don't center on mobile device

Tags: html, css

**Hello!**
Image Elements on mobile devices is not center.

[Large screens](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uCu55.png)

[Small screens (Mobile Device)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uvHrm.jpg)

**HTML**

```
  <center>
    <div id="Navigation">
      <a href="#YourForum"><img id="NavigationItem" src="assets/img/forums.png" /></a>
      <a href="#YourStore"><img id="NavigationItem" src="assets/img/store.png" /></a>
      <a href="#YourVote"><img id="NavigationItem" src="assets/img/vote.png" /></a>
    </div>
  </center>
```

**CSS**

```
#Navigation {
  margin: 6rem auto;
}
#NavigationItem {
  transition: .5s;
  margin-left: 1rem;
}
#NavigationItem:hover {
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.05); transform: scale(1.05);
}
```

Comment: Don't use `<center>` this is deprecated. Use [flexbox to center Elements)(https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)

Comment: Add media query and add responsive image code .responsive {
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @cloned mentioned, using `<center>` is now considered the old-fashioned way of centering items. This was the best option during the pre-flex-box era. The main reason `<center>` is now depreciated is because the web has to be more responsive than ever due to the varying device screen sizes. I would suggest using `display: flex;` on your `#Navigation id` with `justify-content: center;` This is a highly reponsive alternative for what you're trying to accomplish. Also, I added `flex-wrap: nowrap;` to ensure your images don't wrap despite how small the screen gets. Please see the changes below, and insert them into your code.

```css
#Navigation {
  margin: 6rem auto;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
}
#NavigationItem {
  transition: .5s;
  margin-left: 1rem;
}
#NavigationItem:hover {
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.05); transform: scale(1.05);
}
```

```html
<div id="Navigation">
 <a href="#YourForum"><img id="NavigationItem" src="https://dummyimage.com/100x100/000/fff" /></a>
 <a href="#YourStore"><img id="NavigationItem" src="https://dummyimage.com/100x100/000/fff" /></a>
 <a href="#YourVote"><img id="NavigationItem" src="https://dummyimage.com/100x100/000/fff" /></a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding text-align: center to the #Navigation styles, if it doesn't work use flexbox

```
#Container {
     display: flex;
     justify-content: center;
     flex-wrap: wrap;
}
```

NB: enclose each child in a div

Answer (score 0):

You need to use flex/grid.
if you use flex,
give the container a height and

```
display:flex; justify-content:center;align-items:center;flex-wrap:wrap;
```

if your screen is small, the items are not centered in the middle, they Went down a row because of the wrap. if you want that the images will be in the middle, Decrease their size